# I want resize v-chip or other idea to create field with text

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

Good afternoon!
I would like a help to adjust the size of the block where the device, preferably I would like the box to be X px size or something like that. But you have other solution, I would want to see. I'm using vuetify.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w38Mn.png)

```
<template v-slot:item.device="{ item }">
  <v-chip>
    {{ item.device }}
    <v-icon small right @click.stop v-clipboard="item.uid" v-clipboard:success="showCopySnack">mdi-content-copy</v-icon>
  </v-chip>
</template>
```

Comment: do you want the text cut short? should the icon always show? do you want the size to change on hover/click

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a class to the `v-chip` and wrap `item.device` in a span.

```
<v-chip class="short">
    <span>{{item.device}}</span>
    <v-icon small right @click.stop v-clipboard="item.uid" v-clipboard:success="showCopySnack">mdi-content-copy</v-icon>
</v-chip>
```

Then add css, where the v-chip class has the width and the span will ellipse.

```
.short{
  width:100px;
}
.short span{
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

[codepen example](https://codepen.io/depperm/pen/YzXVGZq)